# Can't bind to 'data' since it isn't a known property of 'p-chart'

Tags: angular, primeng

[Link:https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/chart/bar](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/chart/bar)

As given in the above link i tried giving code in .ts and html . And i have installed chart.js and primeng and m getting this error.

Can't bind to 'data' since it isn't a known property of 'p-chart'.

1. If 'p-chart' is an Angular component and it has 'data' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'p-chart' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
   ][data]="data">

"): ng:///AppModule/BarComponent.html@1:20
'p-chart' is not a known element:
1. If 'p-chart' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'p-chart' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
[ERROR ->]

Comment: you need to add `FormsModule`. Here is a link to solve this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45633230/1791913

Comment: Hi Faisal . i have already tried that way but i didn't work

Comment: mmm it look like you've not imported the chart module . .cause it don't know that is p-cahert

Comment: Hi i cleared it. The problem was with import { ChartModule } from 'primeng/primeng';

Comment: WHere to add  import { ChartModule } from 'primeng/primeng'; ?? for me still its showing same error!!

Comment: Hi Shreedhar, I added it in the main AppModule

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38892771/cant-bind-to-ngmodel-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-input)

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to import the ChartModule to your project?:

Import this:

```
import { ChartModule } from 'primeng/chart';
```

and add this to your imports:

```
imports: [
    ChartModule
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

For me: create new child page inside another page.
I haved do this:
in parent.module.ts

```
import { FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import { CoreModule } from '@app/core';
import { SharedModule } from '@app/shared';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { NgxCircularSliderModule } from "@app/shared/ngx-circular-slider/src/public_api";

@NgModule({
entryComponents: [
 ImportDataPopupComponent,ImportDataChartComponent
],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    TranslateModule,
    FormsModule,
    CommonModule,
    TranslateModule,
    CoreModule,
    SharedModule,
    HttpModule,
    NgxCircularSliderModule
  ],
  declarations: [ImportDataComponent,ImportDataPopupComponent,ImportDataChartComponent],
providers: [
ImportDataService
  ]
})
```

I miss these:
    CommonModule,
    TranslateModule,
    CoreModule,
    SharedModule,
    HttpModule,
    NgxCircularSliderModule

after that My chart Appear like a magic!! hope it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You will need import `ChartModule` on your module and add chart.js reference in angular.json, like this:

```
        "scripts": [
          "node_modules/chart.js/dist/chart.js"
        ]
```